# Why do NuGet packages, which are not PCLs, work in Xamarin?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget

I created a .NET class library project for my Xamarin.iOS solution. But when I tried to reference it from my main project, there was the error "Incompatible target framework: .NET Framework,Version=v4.5)".

It looks like I need to create a Xamarin.iOS library project or a Portable Class Library project. Hence, I ask: why can I reference NuGet packages, which I believe are not PCL?

Comment: By the error ""Incompatible target framework: .NET Framework,Version=v4.5)" seems more like an error of framework version.

Comment: Nuget packages often have multiple copies of a DLL, built specifically for each platform target that the package supports.

Comment: Xamarin have special NuGet target frameworks to be able to consume(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/nuget/#NuGet_Package_Xamarin_Profiles). For creating libraries targeting Xamarin, you should use `netstandard` or a framework specific library (iOS/Android).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGet packages can be PCL.  Not all NuGet packages will work with Xamarin; those that do either target Xamarin iOS or Xamarin Android, or target a Xamarin compatible PCL profile.